# Common managed C++ gotchas

Tags: c++-cli, managed-c++

What are some of the most common issues to look out for when writing managed-C++ for the first time after almost exclusively working with unmanaged C++?

Comment: People still use Managed C++? I thought most projects would have switched to C++/CLI already. :-O

Comment: one gotcha is calling it managed C++ (lower case m) because it's managed code, not knowing that before C++/CLI there was Managed C++ (of which we mostly do not speak.)

Comment: Biggest mistake is assuming that it is similar to C++.  Write some C# code first to get a feel for the managed environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert a managed delegate to a pointer-to-function using the built-in IJW (It Just Works) technology, the pointer-to-function is not holding a reference to the object that the delegate was from.  If you don't arrange to hold a reference some other way, the managed object may be collected, and then when you call the function, you'll get a NullReferenceException.

You run into this a lot if you are making a C-library that takes callbacks, and you want to wrap it in a Managed class.  The client to the managed class will provide a delegate, which you convert to the callback.  You must also keep a reference to the delegate or target object.

This is true in Managed C++ and C++/CLI.

Comment: Not C++-specific, this affects all .NET languages.  See [`Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getfunctionpointerfordelegate.aspx).  "The delegate is converted to a function pointer that can be passed to unmanaged code using the `__stdcall` calling convention.
You must manually keep the delegate from being collected by the garbage collector from managed code. The garbage collector does not track reference to unmanaged code."

Answer (score 1):

If you mean C++/CLI...

- Forgetting to use pin_ptr when passing arguments by reference. Related to this, it's vital to understand the difference between a tracking handle and a pointer. See the firsts chapters of [Expert C++/CLI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597567).
- C++/CLI doesn't have C#'s `yield` construct, which we use a lot when writing Unit Tests with Nunit using the TestCaseSource attribute to generate test case data. This is related to the next one.
- Implementing System::IEnumerable is sintactically cumbersome. But once you do it once, you have a reference, so it's not that bad.
- It's very important to understand the difference between destructors and finalizers. For a discussion about this, again, see chapter 4 of [Expert C++/CLI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597567)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another gotcha: Executing a method on an object does *not* constitute a reference to the object.  This means that during execution of a member method the object but after your last reference to `this` the object might be cleaned up while the method is still executing and the finalizer may fire.

If your object has any unmanaged state that is cleaned up by finalization or contains any other object with such unmanaged state are you're doing computations on that unmanaged state, be sure to call `GC::KeepAlive` on `this` after those unmanaged computations.  I now tend to just append `GC::KeepAlive` to all methods of objects with unmanaged computation.

Answer (score 0):

One gotcha (that just got me): assuming "the destructor can only be executed once". Since the destructor is invoked via `Dispose`, and `Dispose` might be called multiple times, this assumption (which is fine for C++) does not hold for C++/CLI.